# join two lists which don't have same length, repeating shortest

Tags: python, list

## I have two lists:

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
l2 = ["a","b","c"]
```

## My expected output:

```
l3 = [(1,"a"),(2,"b"),(3,"c"),(4,"a"),(5,"b")]
```

So basically I'm looking to join two lists and when they are not same lenght i have to spread items from other list by repeating from start.

## I tried:

using zip() but it is bad for this case as it join with equal length

```
>>> list(zip(l1,l2))
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) so that `zip` aggregates elements both from `l1` and a *cycling* version of `l2`:

```
from itertools import cycle

list(zip(l1, cycle(l2)))
# [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'a'), (5, 'b')]
```

---

`cycle` is very useful when the iterable over which you are cycling is combined or *zipped* with other iterables, so the iterating process will stop as soon as some other iterable is exhausted. Otherwise it will keep cycling indefinitely (in the case there is a single `cycle` generator or also that all other iterables are also infinite as @chepner points out)

Comment: How does `cycle` work? when i call it outside zip() it seem to create an endless loop.

Comment: Cycle is mainly useful when combined with some other iterable, so the iterating process stops as soon as another iterable is exhausted, since cycle will otherwise keep cycling indefinitely  @vdkd

Comment: That's exactly what it does, but it does so *lazily*. Since `zip` stops reading from both its arguments once it reaches the end of the shorter one, there's no infinite loop. You would get an infinite loop if you gave `zip` *all* infinite sequences, or if you used `itertools.zip_longest` with at least one infinite sequence.

Comment: Yes @chepner indeed the only way it would iterate indefinitely with other iterables is either if they are also `cycle` generators or as you mention `zip_longest` is used

Comment: `count` and `repeat` also produce infinite sequences, as could a generator function using an infinite loop or unterminated recursion.

Comment: Yep true @chepner :) left it with *infinite* in the post

Comment: I'm just nit-picking, mainly to ward off anticipated questions. The answer is solid.